# How does a shower contribute to the humidity inside a bathroom?

Tags: temperature, humidity, condensation

I would like to know the exact process behind the humidity in a bathroom increasing due to a hot/cold shower.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of vapour pressure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water tends to evaporate into the air, increasing its humidity. Hot water evaporates faster than cold water. Since evaporation happens at the surface between water and air, increasing the surface area increases the overall rate of evaporation. When hot water is shot out of a shower nozzle, it is broken up onto lots of small droplets; the combination of high surface area and hot water causes the air in the bathroom to quickly get humidified.

Air has a limit to its ability to hold water vapor in solution, with hot air being able to hold more vapor than cold air. When that limit is reached, the net rate of evaporation goes to zero.